# Connecting to a cloud PostgreSQL using psycopg2 from an AWS lambda : Timeout and OpenBLAS WARNING

Tags: python, postgresql, aws-lambda, psycopg2

Using a **AWS Lambda function**, I'm trying to connect to a cloud **PostgreSQL** in order to use an SQL query to get a certain information like in the simplified code below. However, I get a timeout no matter how much I increase the memory and timeout configuration.

I also used https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2 but in vain.

I also get the following warning :

*OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k.*

```
import psycopg2
import datetime  
import pandas as pd 


       
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    conn = psycopg2.connect( host="", dbname="", user="", password="")
    
    sql_requests_users = """
    select *
    """
    df_requests_users = pd.read_sql_query(sql_requests_users,conn)
    conn.close()
    
    return "OK"
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the complete error message as seen on the client?  What does the DB server's log file say about it?

Comment: The error is : " Task timed out after 20.02 seconds", the 20 seconds is the time i specified for it in the function's configuration. As for the log : START RequestId:  Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 
REPORT RequestId: Duration: 20021.84 ms Billed Duration: 20000 ms Memory Size: 3008 MB Max Memory Used: 40 MB Init Duration: 174.39 ms 
2022-09-20 Task timed out after 20.02 seconds